# reader.onload: Looping Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I was wondering if it is possible to get this right. I am using a Jquery cropping tool ([cropit](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/)). I am trying to put multiple file inputs into several cropper instances at once. Unfortunately it doesnt work that well.
For example, if I upload three images, the first two croppers are empty and the last one gets one of the images randomly. Here is the function:

```
function handleCropit(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var count = counterCropit();

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload= function(e){ $('#image-cropper'+count).cropit('imageSrc', e.target.result);};
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
function handleCropit(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var count = counterCropit();
        var croper = $('#image-cropper'+count);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload= (function (yo) {return function(e){ yo.cropit('imageSrc', e.target.result);}})(croper);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```